# Using superglobal $_GET in php class

Tags: php, superglobals

Good morning,
I am trying to use superglobal "$_GET" in PHP class, but none of my 4 solutions didn't work... Here is my last try, could someone please tell me what is wrong?
Thank you

```
   public $a;


    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->response = array();

               if(isset($_GET['album']){
            $this->a = $_GET['album'];
        }else{
            $this->a = null
        }

        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',$a,'/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',$a,'/',

......
}
```

Comment: Does your URL contain `?album=<VALUE>` ??

Comment: Sure, it does, I've tried few values..

Comment: you might consider passing the $_GET to the constructor (as a better design approach)

Comment: @zedd well I've found few solutions and every time it was in the constructor like in my code here

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['album']))  //missing paranthesis here.............
{   
        $this->a = $_GET['album'];
}else{
        $this->a = null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are concatenating the url with a comma:

```
 'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',$a,'/',
 'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',$a,'/',
```

But if $a is null you get double slashes. And this line is missing a semicolon

```
$this->a = null
```